# ItemsCollection and alternate row coloring

Tags: wpf, styles, itemscontrol

I've got an itemscollection and I want to have alternate row colouring, I've looked about how to do this but can't find anything, I think this should be simple but maybe I'm missing something.

It's WPF btw.

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=something}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Launch" Tag="{Binding}" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,12" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="button1_Click">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `AlternationCount="2"` to your ItemsControl.

Then add this to your ItemContainerStyle to get alternating red/blue items:

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Edit: you need to have the .NET 3.0/3.5 *SP1*.

Comment: I get cannot resolve style property background when using your example

Comment: The code compiles now, but no alternating colours unfortunatly, I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 styles (one for regular row and the other for alternate row of course) and a style selector for alternate rows. This worked for me:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="theAlternateStyle">
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="LightGray" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="theDefaultStyle">
            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="4">
        <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
                <local:AlternatingRowStyleSelector AlternateStyle="{StaticResource theAlternateStyle}" DefaultStyle="{StaticResource theDefaultStyle}" />
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Row Selector (C#):

```
public class AlternatingRowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public Style DefaultStyle { get; set; }
    public Style AlternateStyle { get; set; }

    // Flag to track the alternate rows
    private bool isAlternate = false;

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // Select the style, based on the value of isAlternate
        Style style = isAlternate ? AlternateStyle : DefaultStyle;

        // Invert the flag
        isAlternate = !isAlternate;

        return style;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 3.5 SP1? If it's a few properties you want to change (like background) then the easiest method is probably a converter as in [this example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx).

An alternative, and one that let you do a fair bit more, including replacing the template, would be to use a Trigger on the ItemsControl.AlternationIndex as demonstrated in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/05/28/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-alternating-rows.aspx).